# I try to use MAP container to map resources, why is this not woring?

Tags: c++

This is giving me an operator error when I compile it. No other error show up.

```
#include <map>

struct RESOURCE {
     char Name[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
     int Level = 0;
};


struct RESOURCEFILE {
      char FileName[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
      DWORD ATTRIBUTE = 0;
};

 map <RESOURCE, RESOURCEFILE> ResourcesMap;

 void PolulateResources(RESOURCE Resource, RESOURCEFILE File){
          ResourcesMap[Resource] = File;
 };
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesn't compile is because you are trying to use a map with key type `RESOURCE`. By default the compare function for `std::map` uses less-than-operator(<) for the key type to order the map. You haven't defined one here.

You can fix the issue by defining a `operator<` for `RESOURCE`:

```
struct RESOURCE {
    char Name[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
    int Level = 0;

    bool operator<(const RESOURCE& other) const
    {
        //write your compare function here...
        //return (strcmp(Name, other.Name) < 0);
    }
};
```

(It might be easier to use `std::string` for `Name` since it already has a operator<).

Alternatively you could define a functor or a lambda for the compare function.

Comment: That allow it to compile, But it does copy all info.

Comment: Does (not) copy _what_ info? If you edit your question to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or ask it in a fresh question, someone might be able to help. Without that, I have no idea what actual problem you're encountering.